# Sizing a groundwater storage well for stormwater runoff; using the area below a patio as a recharge pit

Tags: civil-engineering, water-resources, home-improvement

I would like to build a patio of 900 square feet. My city engineer says that:
"any increase in impervious coverage over 500 square feet must recharge 3-inches of runoff for each square foot of new impervious coverage. The stone area under the patio can be used for groundwater storage and recharge or an alternate design such as a drywell can be installed. The storage area must be designed for the required recharge rate."

**What does "3-inches of runoff" mean? is that a rate or a volume?** **What depth of a pit do I need if I am using the stone area under the patio for groundwater storage?** My zip-code is 07006 and my town code notes that "Stone used in the infiltration devices shall be 2 1/2 inches clean stone, and **design void ratio of 40%** shall be used. "

Comment: 3/12 ft * 400 ft^2 = volume you need to store to drain.  divide by .40 to get volume of pit.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Be careful. One interpretation could be the rule applies for impervious construction of over 500sf. Volume is based on the new construction of 900sf.

Comment: Correct; the town applies it to the whole 900sf.